# Neural network with a custom loss function

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I'm trying to implement a simple neural network (in Python) with 1 hidden layer and a loss function based on the GINI coefficient. But I just cannot find a way to minimize it with gradient descent. I'm not sure if this is even possible with this method. A simplified form can be written this way with e, current vector of errors :
$$ e = y - \hat y $$
$$min\ G(e)=min\sum\limits_i\sum\limits_j \mid e_i-e_j\mid$$

Any idea or a trick to do this ? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? The loss looks (almost everywhere) differentiable to me, so what is the problem?

Comment: Im trying to get the derivative but im stuck due to the presence of absolute values.

Comment: The derivative of $f(x)=|x|$ is $1$ if $x>0$ and $-1$ if $x<0$ and undefined at $x=0$ (look at a plot of $f$). Use the chain rule.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I've copied your comment as an answer. If you'd like to write your own answer, please let me know so that I can delete mine.

Comment: @Sycorax: thanks! I'll go ahead and upvote your answer. And I'll stop answering in comments.

Answer (score 2):

In comments, @StephanKolassa writes

> The derivative of $f(x)=|x|$ is $1$ if $x>0$ and $−1$ if $x<0$ and undefined at $x=0$ (look at a plot of $f$). Use the chain rule.

---

I've copied this comment as a *community wiki* answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

Please review

- [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
- [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)